# Transform a named vector to a named list

Tags: r, list

How to transform this:

```r
inp <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)
```

into this:

```r
list(aa = c(a = 1), bb = c(b = 2), cc = c(c = 3), dd = c(d = 4))
```

`purrr::imap(as.list(r), ~ set_names(.x, .y))` is a good start, but the loop seems to be unnecessary. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option can be:

```
#Code
res <- setNames(split(inp,names(inp)),paste0(names(split(inp,names(inp))),names(split(inp,names(inp)))))
```

Output:

```
$aa
a 
1 

$bb
b 
2 

$cc
c 
3 

$dd
d 
4
```

The more compact solution would be (Many thanks and credits to **@markus**):

```
#Code2
res <- setNames(split(inp , names(inp)), strrep(names(inp), 2))
```

Same output.

Comment: Ah `split`  is an elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: @thothal Always a pleasure helping you :) Kind regards!

Comment: @markus I did not know about that. Let me add that to the post with credit to you so that other people can benefit from it :)

Comment: Outer names are not the most important part about this question so the `split` was the key.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
Map(setNames, setNames(inp, strrep(letters[1:4], 2)), names(inp))
```

-output

```
#$aa
#a 
#1 

#$bb
#b 
#2 

#$cc
#c 
#3 

#$dd
#d 
#4
```